# Can stack word length be different from register word length

Tags: memory, stack, cpu-registers, microprocessors

Are there any examples where the word length of stack word is different from that of register's , for example, registers maybe 4 bytes, memory maybe 2 bytes stack words could be only 1 bytes (so that if register content is pushed to stack, stack pointer would update by 4 and not 1)?? Or there are some specifc considerations against doing this??

Are there any specific examples of Microprocessors where all three (or any two) word lengths are indeed different??
If yes, what was the motivation to do so?

Comment: What is a "stack cell"? On most processors, the stack pointer has the same addressing modes as any general-purpose register. There may be specialized "push" and "pop" instructions, but the standard addressing modes are also available. So if the architecture has a "load one byte from memory" instruction, there is also a "load one byte from stack member" instruction.

Comment: @RaymondChen I meant that stack pointer increment is not -1, but maybe -2 or -4 depending on relative word sizes in registers and stack?

Comment: The case I studied had the stack pointer increment by -1 so both word lengths were equal (in stack and register) but are there exceptions?

Comment: Many architectures support variable-sized stack pointer increments. On x86, `pop ax` increments by 2, `pop eax` by 4, `pop rax` by 8. On ARM, `ldr r0, [sp], N` increments by as much as you like (`N`). In general, RISC architectures let you increment the stack pointer by whatever you like, just like any other general-purpose register.